# WPF Custom Control's Dependency Property unintentionally affecting other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am making a window which is supposed to record the mouse position.  I have created a user control which is supposed to display the current coordinates for that position tag and allow the user to change them.
[image]

It works great except for the fact that when one is updated they all change.

I *think* this has something to do with the fact that dependency properties are statically registered. They need to be dependency properties because I need to be able to Bind them to my model from the xaml.

How can I have the User Controls independent from one another?

```
<UserControl x:Class="SapFormFiller.SerializableMouseEditorControl"
         ...
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
        ...
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="{Binding LabelText}"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs.X}"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs.Y}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0.4,0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Edit</Button>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
public partial class SerializableMouseEditorControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelText", typeof (string), typeof (SerializableMouseEditorControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs", typeof (SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs), typeof (SerializableMouseEditorControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs()));

    public SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs
    {
        get { return (SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs) GetValue(SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgsProperty, value); }
    }
    public SerializableMouseEditorControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs = new SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs.Update();
    }
}
```

SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs:

```
public class SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");

        }
    }
    ...
    IKeyboardMouseEvents gkme;        
    private int _x = 0;
    private int _y=0;

    public override string ToString(){...}
    public SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs()
    {
        gkme = Hook.GlobalEvents();
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        IsEditing = true;
        gkme.MouseClick += Gkme_MouseClick;
    }

    private void Gkme_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.X = e.X;
            this.Y = e.Y;
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            gkme.MouseClick -= Gkme_MouseClick;
            IsEditing = false;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at `gkme.MouseClick -= Gkme_MouseClick;` to make sure that the handler is actually detached?

Comment: The problem is likely that you create `new SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs()` as defaultvalue. That makes it shared among all. Add a nonstatic ctor and set the property from there.

Comment: If I have it set to `default()` then all the dependency properties are `null` and I get null-reference exceptions when clicking the edit button.  and yes, the handler successfully detaches.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
new PropertyMetadata(new SerializableMouseKeyboardEventArgs()));
```

looks like it could be causing you problems. I was in a situation where declaring default values using `new` keyword was causing one instance of the UserControl to share that property value with another instance.

Try initializing any such properties in your constructor and it might work.